# File Upload from Angular to NodeJS Backend to NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload

I'm having troubles forwarding files from my NodeJS web backend to my NodeJS API. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. I just know that there are no files found in the request when it gets to the API. Hopefully someone can clarify what I am missing here.

**API app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/api', routes.api);
```

**API /routes/index.js**

```
exports.api = require('./api');
```

**API /routes/api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

router.post("/file/upload", upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  console.log("==> inside file upload <===");
  console.log(req.files ? req.files.length : -1, " => num files found in request");
  res.status(200).send("File Uploaded");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**API Console Output**

```
==> inside file upload <===
0  => num files found in request
POST /api/file/upload 200 19.037 ms - 13
```

**Angular HTML**

```
<h1 class="text-center">
  Test File Upload
</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8 offset-4">

    <form #frmUpload method="POST" action="/api/file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input #inFile type="file" name="inFile" (change)="submitUpload()" />
    </form>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

**Angular TS**

```
@ViewChild("frmUpload", {static: false}) frmUpload: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("inFile", {static:false}) inFile: ElementRef;


submitUpload() {
    const _form: HTMLFormElement = this.frmUpload.nativeElement;
    _form.submit();
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.inFile.nativeElement.value = "";
    }, 500);
}
```

**NodeJS Web Backend app.js**

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

**NodeJS Web Backend /routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const http = require('http');
const FormData = require('form-data');

router.post('/api/file/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files ? req.files.length : -1, " => num files found in request");
  const { headers, files } = req;
  const { buffer, originalname: filename } = files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', buffer, { filename });
  const postReq = http.request({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    path: "/api/file/upload",
    headers:  formData.getHeaders(),
    method: "POST"
  }, (response) => {
    console.log("api has responded");
  });
  postReq.end(); 
  res.send("<p>File uploaded</p><div style='margin:10px;'><a href='/'>Go Back</a></div>");
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("..... Render Angular ......");
  res.sendFile(Path.resolve('../angular/dist/angular/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**NodeJS Web Backend Console Output**

```
1  => num files found in request
POST /api/file/upload 200 4.226 ms - 75
api has responded
```

Take a look at the API console output. See how it says "0 files found." That is the issue I am having. Look at the Web Backend and you will see the file is there before I attempt to forward it to the API. Any ideas on what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to send the data of your form with a pipe.

```
  const postReq = http.request({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    path: "/api/file/upload",
    headers:  formData.getHeaders(),
    method: "POST"
  }, (response) => {
    console.log("api has responded");
  });
  formData.pipe(postReq);   // <---- add this
```

You don't need the `postReq.end()`.

## To debug:

If you actually wanted to see what you're sending to the API, you could send your form data to a file. It works similarly.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./debug.log');
formData.pipe(writeStream);
```

The content of the file should look like

```
----------------------------132413245123412341234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="filename.ext"
Content-Type: some/mimetype
... followed by the data
```